# Nuitka unicode Hello world error

Tags: python, unicode, nuitka

Just tried to compile very simple program in Nutika (Ubuntu 12.04, latest nuitka frop PyPI) and stuck with problem

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
   print u"Hi Männer"
```

And caught an exception

nuitka test.py

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Googling is not helped. may be someone on stackoverflow says howto compile nutika programms with specific national unicode chars?

Comment: print "Hi Männer" maybe??

Answer (score 0):

This works somehow.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u"Hi Männer".encode('utf-8')
```